ion-checkbox don't let interact with label
Update: added in ionic doc (pr opened)
https://ionic-docs-git-checkbox-link-ionic1.vercel.app/docs/api/checkbox#links-inside-of-labels
I have a ion-checkbox with a <a href="" inside.
If I click on the link part of the label the href don't triggers, instead only works onIonChange.
<ion-checkbox
                                        value={value}
                                        name='name'
                                        onIonChange={(e) => this.handleChangeCheck(e)}
                                        label-placement="end">
                                        <div class="ion-text-wrap">My text <a href="https://google.it"> click here</a></div>
                                    </ion-checkbox>

Ionic version 7x
Code reproduction https://d6xspp.stackblitz.io

the update you shown in the docs link is the same answer i gave to you before..... e.stopPropagation.

One way is to use css prop z-index and js event.stopPropagation():
CSS
.ion-text-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.ion-text-wrap a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1; /* Higher z-index to make the link clickable */
}

JS
<ion-checkbox
  value={value}
  name='name'
  onIonChange={(e) => this.handleChangeCheck(e)}
  label-placement="end">
   <div class="ion-text-wrap">
      My text <a href="https://google.it" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>click here</a>
   </div>
</ion-checkbox>

